# why React native gives the error 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command ?

Tags: android, react-native, adb, react-android

I have tried several options suggested in other related stack overflow questions.

1. I add 'adb' path in the system variable.
2. Create local.properties file and paste my 'sdk' path there.

nothing works for me. I am using android emulator and app is built successfully.

Comment: find the adb binary path and add it to your env path.

Comment: After adding the adb path in system variables, did your try restarting the console and running it again?

Comment: @ASN  i added path manually. so i didn't have any console to restart..

Comment: Try checking this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pILZTnJnuv8). It might be of some help

Comment: why the question mark as duplicate. i have  clearly mentioned that those options are not working for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute-path-for-adb/adb -command instead of writing adb -command

Answer (score 0):

You can open cmd in folder with adb (.../platform-tools). And use it from here, or you can change current directory inside cmd